# UIScrollViews and anchors swift

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift2, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am having trouble setting up a scroll view and actually scrolling down. I populated the scroll view with some textfields and used anchors (topanchor,leftanchor...) to position them inside the scroll view. Even if I set the scroll view height to 1000, it wont actually move, it continues to show the same items, the scroll indicator does go down but the content itself doesnt, I already set the scroll view to scrollenabled, and delegate to self.

I think the problem might be with the anchors but then how will I arrange my items inside the scroll view, any sugestion will be greatly appreaciated.

EDIT : The code below indicates the anchors applied to the scroll view ( inputContainer ), the img corresponds to an UIImageView and the mainContainer to the UIView containing the img and the inputContainer.

```
inputContainer.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( img.bottomAnchor ).active = true
inputContainer.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.leftAnchor ).active = true

inputContainer.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.widthAnchor ).active = true

inputContainerBottomConstraint = inputContainer.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( cancelButton.topAnchor )
inputContainerBottomConstraint?.active = true
```

EDIT: This is how the code looks like :

```
class SView : UIView, UITextFieldDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

let mainContainer : UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    v.layer.masksToBounds = true
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()

let Img : UIImageView = {
    let img = UIImageView()
    img.image = UIImage(named: "noImage")
    img.backgroundColor = .blueColor()
    img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    img.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    img.clipsToBounds = true
    return img
}()

let inputContainer : UIScrollView = {
    let ic = UIScrollView()
    ic.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    ic.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return ic
}()

let datePickerTextField : UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "Fecha"
    tf.textAlignment = .Center
    tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tf
}()

let tagsTextField : UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "Tags"
    tf.textAlignment = .Center
    tf.clearButtonMode = .Always
    tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tf
}()

lazy var cancelButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(255, green: 65, blue: 65, alpha: 1)
    button.setTitle("Cancelar", forState: .Normal)
    button.tintColor = .whiteColor()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    button.addTarget( self , action: #selector(handleCancelButtonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return button
}()

lazy var publicarButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(0 , green: 204, blue: 102, alpha: 1)
    button.setTitle("Publicar", forState: .Normal)
    button.tintColor = .whiteColor()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    button.addTarget( self , action: #selector(handlePublicarButtonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return button
}()


override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)

    inputContainer.delegate = self


    datePickerTextField.delegate = self

    tagsTextField.delegate = self

    setupMainContainer()
    setupImg()
    setupButtons()
    setupInputContainer()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupMainContainer ()
{
    addSubview(mainContainer)

    mainContainer.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( centerXAnchor ).active = true
    mainContainer.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( centerYAnchor ).active = true

    mainContainer.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( widthAnchor ).active = true
    mainContainer.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( heightAnchor )
}

func setupImg ()
{
    mainContainer.addSubview(Img)

    Img.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.topAnchor ).active = true
    Img.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.leftAnchor ).active = true

    Img.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.widthAnchor ).active = true
    Img.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.heightAnchor , multiplier: 0.3).active = true
}

var inputContainerBottomConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint?

func setupInputContainer ()
{
    mainContainer.addSubview(inputContainer)

    inputContainer.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( Img.bottomAnchor ).active = true
    inputContainer.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.leftAnchor ).active = true
    inputContainer.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.rightAnchor ).active = true
    inputContainerBottomConstraint = inputContainer.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( cancelButton.topAnchor )
    inputContainerBottomConstraint?.active = true



    inputContainer.addSubview( datePickerTextField )
    inputContainer.addSubview( tagsTextField )




    datePickerTextField.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( inputContainer.topAnchor ).active = true
    datePickerTextField.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( inputContainer.centerXAnchor ).active = true

    datePickerTextField.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( inputContainer.widthAnchor ).active = true
    datePickerTextField.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( inputContainer.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2 ).active = true


    tagsTextField.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( inputContainer.bottomAnchor ).active = true
    tagsTextField.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( inputContainer.centerXAnchor ).active = true

    tagsTextField.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( inputContainer.widthAnchor ).active = true
    tagsTextField.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( inputContainer.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2 ).active = true

}

func setupButtons()
{
    mainContainer.addSubview( cancelButton )
    mainContainer.addSubview( publicarButton )


    cancelButton.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.bottomAnchor).active = true
    cancelButton.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.leftAnchor ).active = true

    cancelButton.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.widthAnchor, multiplier:  0.5 ).active = true
    cancelButton.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.heightAnchor, multiplier:  0.1).active = true



    publicarButton.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.bottomAnchor).active = true
    publicarButton.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( cancelButton.rightAnchor ).active = true

    publicarButton.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.widthAnchor, multiplier:  0.5 ).active = true
    publicarButton.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor( mainContainer.heightAnchor, multiplier:  0.1).active = true
} }
```

So when the keyboard appears the bottom anchor constant of the scroll view changes so that the keyboard "top anchor" is the new bottom anchor.

Comment: What is `img`, `inputContainer`, and `mainContainer`? It's hard to know if you have the right constraints without knowing more about the view hierarchy. If that's all the constraints you've set, it doesn't seem likely to be enough to satisfy the layout engine.

Comment: Input containter is the scroll view itself, img is an UIimageview, and the mainContainer is the uiview in which the the inputcontainer (scrollview) is contained.

Comment: @beyowulf thanks for your reply, what constraints am I missing? I thought I was setting every possible ambiguity with those constraints, topAnchor for y, leftAnchor for x, width well for width, and height is deduced by the top and bottom constraints. I continue to think the problem relies in setting the content of the inputContainer with anchors, but I dont know what other option could I have

Comment: Okay. That will satisfies for the frame of the scroll view, but what about the scroll view's contents which seems to be where your problem is?

Comment: @beyowulf Each textfield inside the scroll view has a top,left,width and height anchor. The problem relies that these textfields doesnt respond to any of the changes made to the scroll view frame. In other words, when trying to scroll down, the scroll view indicator its actually going down but it keeps showing the same textfields, so its not really moving the content of the scroll view.

Comment: update: I decided to play with the values of the scroll view contentSize, setting its width to something i know its bigger than the view width itself and the height also bigger, the scroll view did actually move horizontally but vertically still the same problem. Still I dont know the answer but i think this could get me a step closer to it.

Answer (score 0):

With the constraints you have described there's no way for the layout engine to determine the content height of the scroll view. You should pin your bottom text field to the bottom of the scroll view. This way the scroll view's content size will resize up to the max y of all of the text fields. Here is some code you can put in a playground to see:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 150))
scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let textField = UITextField()
textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

let otherTextField = UITextField()
otherTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
otherTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

let otherOtherTextField = UITextField()
otherOtherTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
otherOtherTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

scrollView.addSubview(textField)

textField.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.topAnchor).active = true
textField.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.leadingAnchor).active = true
textField.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.widthAnchor).active = true

scrollView.addSubview(otherTextField)

otherTextField.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(textField.bottomAnchor, constant: 60).active = true
otherTextField.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.leadingAnchor).active = true
otherTextField.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.widthAnchor).active = true

scrollView.addSubview(otherOtherTextField)
otherOtherTextField.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(otherTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 60).active = true
otherOtherTextField.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.leadingAnchor).active = true
otherOtherTextField.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.widthAnchor).active = true
otherOtherTextField.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.bottomAnchor).active = true

scrollView.setNeedsLayout()

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = scrollView
```

This places three text fields in a scroll view with 60 points between the center and top and bottom. If you comment out:

```
otherOtherTextField.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.bottomAnchor).active = true
```

The scroll view in the assistant editor will not scroll, but with it it does.

Comment: I changed the last text field bottom anchor to the scroll view bottom anchor and still nothing... maybe it has something to do that you set the scrollview frame rect and I just anchored???

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on without seeing more code or screenshots of your view hierarchy. Is what you're doing not similar to the code I posted?

Comment: The only difference from my code to yours its that I didnt set the scroll view frame as you did, i only set the anchors for it. When a try to set the frame as you but depending on the device frame it wont let me.. When i print the frame it says its 0, I dont know if its because the code is inside a UIView and not in a UIViewController. But it keeps printing 0

Comment: I will update the post eith more code when I get home. Thanks for helping me! Really appreciated

Comment: I don't understand your layout. What do you want your input container to look like? As it is, your tags text field doesn't have a y position and that is why it doesn't show up. Also you are making the height of your text fields 20% of the frame height of your scroll view 20 + 20 = 40. A scroll view will only scroll if its contents exceeds 100% of either the height or width of its frame.

Comment: That code isn't the actual code, it is missing a couple other textfields, its just to show how I was setting the input container and it subviews. But ignoring the fact of how many textfields i set in this, if i set the scroll view content size width to something much bigger and the height also to somethig much bigger. The scroll actually scrolls horizontally, I can see a blank space, but with the height this isn't happening, the scroll view indicator its going down but It isnt showing me that blank space, no matter how much I scroll down it continues to show the same textfields

Comment: I can't tell you why that's happening without seeing the actual code. But the scroll view not scrolling has nothing to do with the approach of using constraints to layout you scroll view and its contents. More likely you are missing constraints somewhere, like `tagsTextField` was missing a vertical position, so the layout engine is not satisfied, causing it to behave in an undefined manner.

Comment: I finally found out what happen! I wasn't checking the constraints because I thought they were okay, but when you told me about not setting properly the vertical position I rechecked every constraint and the first textfield top anchor wasnt set to have its top anchor equal to the scroll view's but to the img, after changing that the scroll view finally scrolled down.